# How to find the second half of an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I am able to find the FIRST half of an array using:

```
def first_half(array)
  new_array = []

  i = 0
  while i < (array.length / 2.0)
    ele = array[i]
    new_array << ele

    i += 1
  end

  return new_array
end

print first_half(["John", "Jack", "Jim", "Thomas"])
```

How do I use a `while` loop and find the second half of an array?

Comment: I am trying to learn ruby on my own, so rest assured, no homework haha!

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading Ruby's [Enumerable documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html) several times. The real answer you seek is covered  there. And, like most programming languages, TIMTOWTDI. Your question is missing your expected output. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Why does it have to use a `while` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go though the whole array and add the element only if it passes your condition

```
i = 0
while i < array.length
  ele = array[i]
  if i < array.length / 2.0
    new_array << ele
  end
  i += 1
end
```

now you can change just the if condition

Answer (score 0):

You already do calculate the first half of the array in an unnecessarily complicated way. For an array  `a`, the expression `a[i..n]` returns the array elements at position `i` to `n` (the `..` is an operator to construct a `Range`).

The main problem is that you have to decide for arrays with an odd number of elements, whether the middle one should go to the first or second half. Hence, in your case:

```
first_half = array[0..(array.length/2-1)]
second_half = array[(array.length/2)..(array.length-1)]
```